# Including libraries from node_modules in Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, reactjs

I am creating a ReactJs and wordpress plugin. I have created the standalone Reactjs control and I now want to include my reactJS libraries in the node_modules folder in my wordpress php file like so. Is this the right way to do it? Wordpress is able to find the node_modules folder and the libraries that I have enqueued but not the libraries that the enqueued files depend on(which are present in the node_modules folder).

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'FacebookAlbums_enqueue_scripts' );
function FacebookAlbums_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'react', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'node_modules/react/umd/react.production.min.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'react-dom', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'node_modules/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'react-slick', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'node_modules/react-slick/lib/slider.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'react-image-lightbox', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'node_modules/react-image-lightbox/dist/main.js' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'babel', 'https://npmcdn.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js', '', null, false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'FacebookAlbums', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'FacebookAlbums.js' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'FacebookAlbums', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'FacebookAlbums.css' );
}
```

Comment: So is it `-` or `_` in node-modules?

Comment: @lawrence Cherone, facepalm. Sorry.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: i have added more information to the problem that I am having.

Comment: Question changed lol, your need to include them too or build into a single file.

Comment: So the downvoters, care to explain why you have downvoted? Is this a rudimentary\newbie question?

Comment: Wasn't me, people downvote as its free.

Answer (score 0):

Place this file in the same folder as your package.json that contains your dependencies:

```
<?php

// the generic wp node_modules loader

$package = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/package.json');

$package = json_decode($package, true);

foreach ($package['dependencies'] as $dep => $version) {
    $subpackage = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/node_modules/$dep/package.json");
    $subpackage = json_decode($subpackage, true);

    $use = 'main';

    if (isset($subpackage['browser'])) {
        $use = 'browser';
    }

    if (isset($subpackage[$use])) {
        $deps = array();

        if (strpos($dep, 'jquery') !== false) {
            $deps[] = 'jquery';
        }

        wp_enqueue_script("node_module-$dep", plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . "node_modules/$dep/" . $subpackage[$use], $deps, $subpackage['version']);
    }

    if (isset($subpackage['style'])) {

        wp_enqueue_style("node_module-$dep", plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . "node_modules/$dep/" . $subpackage['style']);
    }
}
```

You'll need to require this file somewhere in your plugin. (This will not work with 100% of packages, modify it according to your project - this is a work in progress).